# Executing multiple sql statements batch concerns?

Tags: java, mysql, database, batch-processing

I am working with mysql in Java.

Basically, I have multiple queries that each create a table in the database, along with a single `ALTER` statement that adjusts the auto-increment initial value for one of my attributes.  I am executing those queries as a transaction--namely either all are committed to the database or none are.  But to do so I have create a separate `Statement` for each query - 8 in total - and execute each.  After, I commit all the results.  And then I have to close each `Statement`.

But this seems inefficient.  To many `Statements`.  So I wonder whether batch methods would work.  My concern is that batch methods execute all the queries simultaneously, and since I have `Referential Integrity Constraints` and the `ALTER` query there is a dependancy between the tables - and thus the order in which they are created matters.  Is this not correct ?  Am I misunderstanding how batch statements work ?

If my logic above is correct, then should I possibly group a few queries together (that are not related) and use batch methods to execute them.  This will then reduce the number of `Statements` I have.

Comment: In MySQL, you can probably just [use a single `Statement`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement) and pass it a string that includes all the SQL statements, separated with a semicolon (`;`). Have you tried this? Also, all DDL statements [cause an implicit commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197013/transactional-ddl-workflow-for-mysql), so executing them within a separate transaction doesn't really matter.

Comment: Issue with the single Statement is readability since I'm creating about 7 tables each contain about 7-12 attributes, in addition to checks, foreign keys, and primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can batch [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) (i.e. *create*, *drop*, *alter*). Also, it's not a great idea, performance wise, to require dynamic **DDL**.

You can batch [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements using [`Statement.addBatch(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch-java.lang.String-) (i.e. *select*, *insert*, *update* and *delete* statements) and then call [`Statement.executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch--).