# C# TransactionScope class is not rolling back the operation after an exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been exploring the TransactionScope class.

I have a simple code interacting with database and inserting data into a table.

```cs
private MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
    string connectionStr
        = "server=127.0.0.1;database=test;uid=root";

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStr);
    conn.Open();

    return conn;
}
```

```cs
var dropTableIfExist = new MySqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "Drop Table IF EXISTS People",
    CommandType = CommandType.Text
};

var createTable = new MySqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "Create Table People (id integer auto_increment primary key, name varchar(15) not null)",
    CommandType = CommandType.Text
};

var insertion1 = new MySqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "Insert into People (name) values ('Bob')",
    CommandType = CommandType.Text
};

var badInsertion1 = new MySqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "Insert into People (name) values (null)",
    CommandType = CommandType.Text
};

try
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            dropTableIfExist.Connection = conn;
            dropTableIfExist.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Creates a new table called people with a name column 
            createTable.Connection = conn;
            createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Inserts 'Bob' into the people table
            insertion1.Connection = conn;
            insertion1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Inserts null into the new table and an exception (Column 'name' cannot be null) gets thrown
            badInsertion1.Connection = conn;
            badInsertion1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

From what I read I thought the database will end up with no table since `scope.Complete()` will not get called and all the operations (creating the people table and inserting 'Bob') will get rolled back. However, in the database the people table gets created and 'Bob' gets inserted.

I'm confused with how the roll back mechanism works. Could someone please explain this to me?

I have read the documentation and tried to understand it but I could not figure out what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Please include the code not shown like `CreateConnection` so there is an [mcve], something anyone could copy/paste into a console app and execute to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Igor I have added more code. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Before executing this code, does the `People` table exist? Also - does MySql support transactions on schema operations? Ah - MySql implicitly commits schema operations: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transactional DDL workflow for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197013/transactional-ddl-workflow-for-mysql)